# Serial Communication from Arduino to XCTU

Tags: serial-port, arduino, communication

I have tested following scenario and experiencing problem.

I have two XBee modules. Both are mounted on Arduno. I configured them using XCTU.

I Choosed:

```
modem= XB24-B
ZNET 2.5 CORDINATOR API
1147
```

and

```
modem= XB24-B
ZNET 2.5 ROUTER/END DEVICE API
1347
```

On Arduino (Say A), I tried following code:

```
Serial.Write ("Hello World "); 
delay(2000);
```

I am expecting to receive `Hello World` on Arduino (Say B for which I have invoked XCTU Terminal). But I received nothing.

If I manually enter `Hello World` in Arduino Console, then I only receive  `Hello World` in  XCTU Termianl.

Please suggest me, how to transmit bytes from A to B.

Comment: I got the answer . Jumper setting was not done .